# How to unset last item in multidimensional array?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, unset

I have a array like below

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Date
            [1] => Name
            [2] => Hours
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2013-01-02
            [1] => Test User
            [2] => 7:59
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2013-01-03
            [1] => Test User
            [2] => 7:53
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2013-01-04
            [1] => Test User
            [2] => 8:12
        )
    .
    .
    .
    .
    [16] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
        [1] => Total
        [2] => 103:1
    )
    [17] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )
)
```

And want to remove last item from array, I have tried [array_pop](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php) but this is not working after passing above array to array_pop gives me output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
)
```

How can I achieve this with minimum code.

Comment: Well, what does "not working" mean? Does it do nothing? Make an error? Crash your computer? Make flying monkeys fall from the sky? Give you free waffles? Please clarify.

Comment: If aways be numeric array you can remove like this unset(array[count(array)-1]);

Comment: "I tried `array_pop`". It's good to know that, but it would be even better if you showed us exactly what code you tried.

Comment: Notice that `array_pop()` modifies array and returns its last element. That's why you get `array([0]=>)`. It is element with key `17` in your initial array.

Comment: exactly what Maxim said.. array_pop works fine, but you appear to be using it wrong.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try:

```
unset ($array_name[count($array_name)-1]);
```

Comment: This answer is unnecessarily complex and the OP would be just as prone to the same mistake if implemented in the same fashion as `array_pop()` (which is the native function which does what this answer does). No researchers should be using this technique to remove the last element in an indexed array.

Answer (score 2):

```
$callback = function(&$array) { array_pop($array); };
array_walk($array, $callback);
```

This will pop the last element from each triplet.

Comment: I don't see where the OP is asking for this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
$my_cnt = count($my_arr);
unset($my_arr[$my_cnt-1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

if all your arrays are indexed by numbers from zero to max without any breaks, you can use

```
unset($ar[count($ar)-1]);
```

otherwise try

```
end($ar);
unset($ar[key($ar)]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing the "popped" element instead of the modified array.

`array_pop()` returns the data in the element that it removes from the array.

This means that you wrote:

```
print_r(array_pop($array));
```

Instead, modify the array with `array_pop()`, then print the array.

```
array_pop($array);
print_r($array);
```